# How can I configure KeepassXC's autotype to type a password from a different entry?

Tags: keepassxc

I have a strange situation, in which a user has two different passwords. On some fields I have to enter password A, on some I have to enter password B, and on some I have to enter A and B.

So far, I have solved this by having two different Keepass entries, in which one holds the username, and the other references it, via `{REF:U@I:.....}`.

However, when attempting to set up auto-type for the field in which both passwords A and B are needed, I can't seem to reference the password during the autotype sequence. Here is what I tried:

```
{USERNAME}{TAB}{PASSWORD}{TAB}{REF:P@I:....}{ENTER}
```

However, KeepassXC complained that this was invalid syntax.

I also attempted to create a local attribute, which I could reference as `{S:otherPw}`. This succeeded, as in autotype inserted whatever the attribute was. However, when I inserted {REF:P@I:....}` as the attribute value, it would literally print those characters and not resolve the reference.

My current workaround is to keep the password of the first entry duplicated in an attribute of the second entry. However, I dislike this setup, as it means I have to duplicate data, when it is clearly supposed to be a reference.

What do I need to do to reference a password in a different entry during autotype?

Comment: I do this by having one password in the KeyPass / KeepassC database and then the extra password as information in the notes field. Works fine.

Comment: @John I assume it's not possible then?

Comment: Not in the password field (I checked through KeePass. The only other way is to have another data line which I think you tried and I do not like either.

Comment: Maybe it was a bug, as I have just tried with KeePassXC 2.7.4, and I can perfectly refer a password from another entry in autotype using the {REF:P@I:BLABLABLA} syntax.